# ng-show/ng-if not working on google autocomplete pac-container custom result

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I have added a custom result to my google places autocomplete pac-container with the following code-

```
angular.element('.pac-container').addClass('location-autocomplete-container');
var el = angular.element('<div id="cantFind" class="pac-item cant-find-location">' +
                        '<i class="mdi mdi-magnify text-info"></i><a class="text-info" href="#">Can\'t find your location?</a></div>');
angular.element(".pac-container").append(el);
```

I want to hide this result in a particular variable condition. Say the variable name is showCantFindResult. ng-show/ng-if is not working on the div of cantFind. Is there any way to show/hide the div on the basis of variable value?